# Case of first impression

Tags: discussion

(Applicable at least in the United States) Should we have a tag for cases of first impression?

This would be for drawing parellels between current and past cases to develop ideas about how the court would rule in new areas of law.

Comment: If you ask a question that calls for that tag you can create the tag as part of the process of asking the question. After adding it to the tag line you can even go and suggest a tag definition so that others will understand what you are intending it to be used for.